# How to achieve date filtering in Angular2

Tags: angularjs, angular, date-format

I have a class inside of which I want to use date filtering as it used to be in Angular 1:

```
$filter('date')(startDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss')
```

Now I want to achieve this using Angular 2. As far as I can see, I could use DatePipe class. But the problem is that I don't know how to import it inside of my class file:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core'
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { InputValidatorService }  from './input-validator.service';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

...

myFunctionInsideOfAClass(){
   var datePipe = new DatePipe(); // Symbol 'DatePipe' can not be properly resolved, probably it is located in inaccessible module.
}
```

How can I achieve this?

EDIT: My app module:

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

..
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule],
    declarations: [AppComponent, MapComponent, AtileLayerDirective, MapDirective, mapControlDirective, ToolsComponent, SearchComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [{
        provide: Http,
        useFactory: (_backend: ConnectionBackend, _defaultOptions: RequestOptions) => new HttpInterceptor(_backend, _defaultOptions),
        deps: [XHRBackend, RequestOptions]
    }, mapManager, SearchService, StatusIconProvider
    ]
})
```

Comment: Did you add `CommonModule` or `BrowserModule` to the component where you are using `DatePipe`? You probably need to explicitly provide it in `@NgModule({ providers: [DatePipe], ...})` The `DatePipe` is also not to filter dates but to format dates.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer No, I haven't added it.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer when I tried to add it in my NgModule it got red with the same message. Do I need to import something additional? 

PS: Sorry for the lame question but I am completely new to angular

Comment: I don't understand what you try to accomplish. Why do you think the `DatePipe` is useful with your problem? You need to import every class that is mentioned in your code.

Comment: As I mentioned in my post in the first code snippet, I want to achieve the same(date formatting) but with Angular2.

Comment: Sorry, found this filter <--> formatting confusing. Can you please edit your question and add the code as you have it now? (also the `NgModule()`)

Comment: I added it. I would like to have the ability to format dates somehow. As I understood there must be DatePipe class which can be used for that purpose. In this case, I don't know what to put in the 'import' section and @ngModule itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';

@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [ /* other providers */, DatePipe],
  ...
})
```